# How to process an error in JavaScript from a parent window that happened in a child window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling

Let's say we have an application and it's running in *window1* (parent window). Then we open a child window (*window2*), but the executive code for it is in window1 (DOM event listeners, etc).

For an example we have a button inside of *window2*, but an event handler for **onclick** event is in *window1*.

The problem is that, when we have some error inside of that handler, an error will appear inside of window2 together with error.stack and error.message, but in window1 we will see nothing.

Of course we can wrap the whole code of that handler in **try...catch statement**, but we will not get errors.stack and there will be only one argument as a string, that contains error.message.

As for me wrapping every handler in **try...catch statement** has a few minuses:

1. Extra code
2. No stack for errors
3. Sometimes we can just forget to add a **try...catch statement**
4. Worse code readability

So maybe there is a better way of how to handle such errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you could declare an `onerror` handler in the child window, and use it to redirect the execution to some function in the parent window.

The child window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>error-child</title>
    </head>
    <body onerror="window.opener.myErrorHandler(event)">
        <h1>error-child</h1>
        <button onclick="invalidReference.method()">produce error</button>
        <button onclick="alert('OK')">do something</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The parent window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>error-parent</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myErrorHandler(event)
            {
                alert("Parent window has received an error from the child window: "+event);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>error-parent</h1>
        <button onclick="window.open('error-child.html')">open child window</button>
    </body>
</html>
```